# How to set a distinct title for each set of data in a parameterized test in testng?

Tags: testng, title, allure, testng-dataprovider

I want to see a different title in each test case.

Now the title is created from the method name.

[Same titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVYXI.jpg)

Is it possible to get a title somehow as a step?

```
@Title("Maybe as step: {0}?????")
@Step("{0}")
@Test(dataProviderClass = Sorm3ExtractMainTest.class, dataProvider = "getJsonForDictDependDwlTest")
public void Sorm3ExtractDictDependDwlTest
  {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement [`ITest`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITest.html), you should be able to specify the test name you want.

```
public class YourClass implements ITest {
  private String name;

  @Step("{0}")
  @Test(dataProviderClass = Sorm3ExtractMainTest.class, dataProvider = "getJsonForDictDependDwlTest")
  public void Sorm3ExtractDictDependDwlTest {
     name = "Maybe as step: {0}?????";
     ...
  }

  @Override
  public String getTestName() {
    return name;
  }
```

Comment: This solution does not work properly :(
Name is specified for the next test.

Test cases:
    Null [Test Case 1208495];
    Test case 1208495 [Test Case 1208658]

Comment: Maybe a TestNG and/or Allure issue. Btw, if possible, you can try to move the dataprovider on a factory constructor: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's just not implemented in TestNG adaptor. You just need to fix it for yourself and use instead of default Allure TestNG adaptor. For `onTestStart()` fix `new TestCaseStartedEvent(...).withLabels()` just add `.withTitle()`. Do not forget about NPE check.